# Adding SQL Server Index On Boolean Column For Perfomance

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing

I have a conditional statement below in a heavy stored procedure. 25% of the rows have a Visible=1 criteria but the rest don't and are not used in the web application, just a reference that it was processed.  Would it be beneficial to add an index to that column?

```
WHERE 
   ev.Visible = 1 AND
   (@StartDate IS NULL OR @StartDate <= ev.StartDate)
```

Comment: This is something that you can test yourself. We don't have your data set. What *exactly* are you looking for?

Comment: Im wondering if its a bad practice to do that, if not, yea I will give it a try.

Comment: Well you don't want to add an index for every query. If you see that the query is not performing optimally, it's frequently used, that it may benefit from an index, then I don't see why not.

Comment: Couldn't agree with @FreshPrinceOfSO more it's hard to give indexing advice without knowing more about your situation. Indexes are beneficial but also have a cost associated with them. It all depends on how often this query is run and what the additional `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` cost of having the index on that table.

Comment: It also depends what follows after the `AND`. You may benefit more from another index or a composite index (that includes the `Visible` column) or a partial index or a composite and partial one.

Comment: Right now the default is the current date following the Visible = 1 which is dynamic since each day gives a different date.

Comment: There isnt a ton of insert or updates, maybe 5-10 inserts a day.  I do run a bulk insert/update at night.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice possible is to test on your actual data and decide upon your findings.

25% selectivity is not very good on larger volumes. Test it on your data to verify. You will probably be doing other kind of searching that will require other indexes.

There are several options to better handle this scenario:

- Depending on what the other predicates in those WHERE clauses are, you might want to consider using a filtered index. 
  `CREATE INDEX [IX_Post_Startdate] ON dbo.Posts(StartDate) WHERE VISIBLE = 1`. This will give support to your other queries that are searching based on startDate.
- If **ALL** your queries are using the same pattern (Visible = 1 AND ...), then partitioning could be a good approach.

  - Partitioning is an enterprise feature so if you are not using that edition then you can manually partition the data by moving "invisible" rows to some kind of archive table.
- If you have few INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and many SELECT statements then using an indexed view could prove to be a good solution.

Comment: *"SQL Server will only use a single index"* source for this?

Comment: Per table per query yes. It will do index seek in the nonclustered index and then lookup in the clustered index. It will not use additional indexes. Will see if I can find a source.

Comment: Bad wording on my part, removed erroneous statement